# Inline javascript popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<a href="javascript:var wechat_left = (screen.width/2)-(200/2);var wechat_top = (screen.height/2)-(210/2);var wechat = window.open ('http://example.html','wechat','left='+wechat_left+',top='+wechat_top+',directories=0,titlebar=0,toolbar=0,location=0,status=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,width=200,height=210');" target="_blank">foo</a>
```

I am having this for a window popup, but in `IE` it will launch in new windows. 
Unfortunately I am not able to change the target due to `CMS restriction`. Is there way to perform cross browser `preventDefault inline`?

Comment: If your CMS don't allow to change link code, change CMS than.